# Is it possible to calculate a maximum pressure attainable with a soda vinegar reaction?

Tags: equilibrium

Given Le Chatelier's principle, there must be a peak pressure of $\ce{CO2}$, at which, under room temperature, the reaction of soda with vinegar would stop?

$$\ce{Na2CO3 + 2 CH3COOH -> CO2 + 2 CH3COONa + H2O}$$

Is my reasoning correct and if so what formula to use to calculate it?

Comment: You're right, and there is no simple formula. Much too complex, the problem. ;)

Comment: It's not just a matter of pressure, but pH and it's dependence on CO2 solubility, and acetate's too.

Comment: Take CO2 solubility and all respective dissociation constants and calculate the equilibrium. There is no simple formula for it, at least not without significant problem simplification. It leads to a set of several nonlinear equations for several variables.

Comment: Note that very high activity of $\ce{CO2}$ may replace reaction with acetic acid by its own reaction $\ce{Na2CO3(aq) + CO2(aq) + H2O -> 2 NaHCO3(aq)}$

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you need to add details (physical state of species, type of container) at least to the extent that you could imagine doing an experiment to measure the equilibrium pressure.